# How to write equality of logical sentences?

Tags: logic

Is it correct to use "=" to show that logical sentence is equal to another one?
Example

$p: 5 = 2 * 2 + 1$

$q = \tilde{} p$

or maybe

$q: \tilde{}p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be confusing to use "$=$" for equality of sentences, since it might also show up in the sentences themselves (as you indicate). One common notation is "$\equiv$" - the latex for this is "$\backslash$equiv".